# Saturation of the Babenko–Beckner inequality

Tags: inequality, fourier-analysis, normed-spaces

The [Babenko-Beckner inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babenko%E2%80%93Beckner_inequality)

$|| \mathcal F f ||_q \geq C(q,p)||f||_p$

is a well-established theorem. It relates the $q$-Norm of a Fourier transform $\mathcal F f$ of a function $f$ to its $p$-Norm, where $1/q+1/p=1$. For a constant

$C(q,p) = \sqrt{p^{1/p}/q^{1/q}}$

this bound is said to be sharp. In particular, it is said to be saturated by Gaussians. However, nobody seems to explicitly state that Gaussians are the *only* functions which allow saturation, including the [original reference](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0608116v2) (I have to admit that I do not completely understand the original proof).

**Therefore, my question is: Are Gaussians the only functions which saturate the Babenko-Beckner inequality or is equality in principle also possible for different kind of functions?**

Comment: You probably want to reverse your inequality. For example, we have $\Vert \mathcal{F}f\Vert_\infty \leq \Vert f \Vert_1$, but not vice versa. I think that Lieb proves that Gaussians are the only functions making this estimate sharp. You should have a look at the book "Analysis" by Lieb & Loss.